# Convert the function to use typescript types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have of following function:

```
const selector = (definitions, query = {}) => {
  const select = {};

  Object.keys(definitions).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof query[key] !== 'undefined') {
      if (definitions[key].validation(query[key])) {
        if (typeof definitions[key].convert !== 'undefined') {
          select[key] = definitions[key].convert(query[key], key);
        } else {
          select[key] = query[key];
        }
      } else if (typeof definitions[key].default !== 'undefined') {
        select[key] = definitions[key].default;
      }
    } else if (typeof definitions[key].default !== 'undefined') {
      select[key] = definitions[key].default;
    }
  });

  return select;
};
```

This typescript is report me that a need to type correcty `definitions` and `query` but i really don't know how.

Error Message.
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.`

How can I do it?

---

Usage:

```js
const config = {
  name: {
    validation: val => val.length >= 3
  },
  page: {
    validation: val => Number.isInteger(parseInt(val, 10)),
    default: 1,
  },
  limit: {
    default: 10,
  }
}

const myQuery = {
  name: 'da',
  page: 'no-unber',
  another: '1',
}
select(config, myQuery)
```

Test

```js
const expected = JSON.stringify({
  page: 1,
  limit: 10,
})
const output = JSON.stringify(selector(config, myQuery))

if (expected !== output) {
  throw new Error(`The output is wrong.\nExpected: ${expected}\nOutput: ${output}`)
}
```

Case of usage: https://jsbin.com/gatojir/edit?js,console

Note: `validation` is required, but `convert`, and `default` are optional parameters.

Comment: `typescript-typings` tag is for questions related pulling in type definitions for third-party libraries. It is not clear, but it seems like that tag is not needed for this question.

Comment: Oh, thanks for said that, I will remove it.

Comment: Can you provide one or more use case examples plz? `const result = selector({ tbd }, { tbd }); expect(result).toEqual(tbd);`. Hence, it will be possible to have an appropriate type for the input parameters `definitions` and `query` and the output. Then Nicholas' answer can fit or another solution more generic (not just for string).

Comment: Based on this, I added my own response, not totally accurate but still interesting I think. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55969899/8634147

Answer (score 1):

An index signature is when you specify that the various keys of an object will correspond to a certain type, even though you don't know ahead of time exactly which keys those will be (or don't want to enumerate them).

For example, your definitions parameter might be defined something like this:

```
interface definition {
  validation?: (arg: any) => boolean;
  convert?: (arg0: any, arg1: any) => any;
  default?: number;
}

interface definitionsCollection {
  [key: string]: definition; // <--- this is an index signature
}

const selector = (definitions: definitionsCollection, query = {}) => {
  // ... etc
}
```

Be aware that your code has another problem: You're calling `definitions[key].validation(query[key])` without making sure that `definitions[key].validation` is defined first. You describe it as being required, but then your own example shows that it may not exist, since `limit` has no validation function. If you need to support the case where validation doesn't exist, you'll need to add that check in:

```
  Object.keys(definitions).forEach((key) => {
    const def = definitions[key];
    if (typeof query[key] !== 'undefined') {
      if (typeof def.validation !== 'undefined' && def.validation(query[key])) {
        if (typeof def.convert !== 'undefined') {
          select[key] = def.convert(query[key], key);
        } else {
          select[key] = query[key];
        }
      } else if (typeof def.default !== 'undefined') {
        select[key] = def.default;
      }
    } else if (typeof def.default !== 'undefined') {
      select[key] = def.default;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Type `(any) => boolean` will also generate the `implicit 'any'` error, it should rather be `(arg: any) => boolean` (or even better is to give the argument meaningful name instead of `arg`).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've updated it to `(arg: any)`, though i agree they should give it more meaningful names and types (i just don't know what those names and types are)

Comment: I'm having another problem, please check this example https://repl.it/repls/FrigidDownrightCone @NicholasTower

Comment: @DavidCosta My answer was given before you added in examples of the data. So i had to guess some of the types, and i guessed wrong. I've updated the answer to make default a number, and to make all of the properties optional.

Answer (score 0):

[nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3794812/nicholas-tower) provided a good solution for the `definition` argument. We can enhance it a bit to be generic and more explicit, and give a type for the `query` argument:

```
type QueryValue = any;
type Query = { [key: string]: QueryValue };

type Definition<T1, T2=T1> = {
  validation?: (value: QueryValue) => boolean;
  convert   ?: (value: QueryValue, key: string) => T1;
  default   ?: T2;
};
```

Notes:

- The type alias `QueryValue` helps clarifying where a value from the `query` is used in a `definition`.
- `definitions` type will not have the type `definitionsCollection` [suggested by nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55940309/8634147) but a generic type `D`. It's less user-friendly when calling the `selector()` function the but it's the only way to infer the value type for each keys.

For the **return type** (currently `{}`!), it's a real challenge. We need to select only some keys in both the `definitions` and the `query`, some of these keys being optional, depending of the result of `validation()` method of the definition.

The basic idea is to create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like `Partial`, combined with some [conditional types criteria](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) with type inference.

To select the keys, we cannot play with the `never` type for the value: the type `{ a: never }` is not reduced to `{}`. We have to filter the keys "inline", recompose the object with the filtered keys and extract these keys! I took this idea from the `FunctionPropertyNames<T>` found amongst [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

To differentiate keys that are optional, we have no choice but splitting the definition in 2 and recombining them in an intersection type: `type T = { K: V } & { K?: V }`. Indeed, `{ K: V|undefined }` is not equivalent to `{ K?: V }`.

With some helper types and handling different cases, the result is:

```
type WithValidation = { validation: (value: QueryValue) => boolean; }
type WithConvert<T> = { convert   : (value: QueryValue, key: string) => T; }
type WithDefault<T> = { default   : T; }

type SelectorResult<D> = {
  [P in {
    [K in keyof D]:
      D[K] extends WithDefault<any> ? K : never
  }[keyof D]]:
    D[P] extends WithDefault<infer T> ? T : never;
} & {
  [P in {
    [K in keyof D]:
      D[K] extends WithDefault<any> ? never :
      D[K] extends WithConvert<any> ?
      D[K] extends WithValidation   ? K : never :
      D[K] extends Definition<any>  ? K : never
  }[keyof D]]?:
    D[P] extends WithValidation & WithConvert<infer T> ? T :
    D[P] extends Definition<any> ? unknown : never;
};
```

We can use some "test types" that can be evaluated in the editor to validate the `SelectorResult` type. The results are good, but it would have been better if the intersection types have been merged:

```
type Test1 = SelectorResult<{ a: 'invalid' }>;
// Not a `Definition<T>`
// => Expected `{}`
// >> Received `{} & {}` : OK

type Test2 = SelectorResult<{ a: any }>;
// ~`Definition<unknown>`
// => Expected `{ a?: unknown }`
// >> Received `{ a: {} } & { a?: unknown }` : ~OK

type Test3 = SelectorResult<{ a: WithConvert<any> }>;
// `convert` alone is ignored.
// => Expected `{}`
// >> Received `{} & {}` : OK

type Test4 = SelectorResult<{ a: WithDefault<number> }>;
// `default` ensures the key is kept and provides the value type: `number`.
// => Expected `{ a: number }`
// >> Received `{ a: number } & {}` : OK

type Test5 = SelectorResult<{ a: WithDefault<number> & WithConvert<any> }>;
// Idem Test 4: `convert()` still ignored, only `default` matters.
// => Expected `{ a: number }`
// >> Received `{ a: number } & {}` : OK

type Test6 = SelectorResult<{ a: WithValidation }>;
// `validation()` alone makes the key optional and the value type `unknown`.
// => Expected `{ a?: unknown }`
// >> Received `{} & { a?: unknown }` : OK

type Test7 = SelectorResult<{ a: WithValidation & WithConvert<string> }>;
// Idem Test6 + `convert()` providing the value type: `string`
// => Expected `{ a?: string }`
// >> Received `{} & { a?: string | undefined }` : OK

type Test8 = SelectorResult<{ a: WithDefault<number>; b: 'invalid'; c: WithValidation }>;;
// Combining several keys from different cases: a (Test4), b (Test1), c (Test6)
// => Expected `{ a: number; c?: unknown }`
// >> Received `{ a: number } & { c?: unknown }` : OK
```

The type usage can be found in the following code, with a little refactoring to be a bit more functional:

```
const keySelector = <D, Q>(definitions: D, query: Q, key: string) => {
  const val = query[key as keyof Q];
  const def = definitions[key as keyof D] as Definition<D[keyof D]>;

  if (typeof val !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof def.validation !== 'undefined' &&
      def.validation(val)) {
    return typeof def.convert !== 'undefined'
        ? { [key]: def.convert(val, key) }
        : { [key]: val };
  }

  return typeof def.default !== 'undefined'
      ? { [key]: def.default }
      : {};
};

const safeSelector = <D>(definitions: D, query: Query) =>
  Object.keys(definitions).reduce(
    (result, key) => Object.assign(result, keySelector(definitions, query, key)),
    {} as SelectorResult<D>);

const selector = <D>(definitions: D, query: Query = {}) =>
  safeSelector(definitions, query || {});
```

These are the unit tests used to avoid regressions:

```
// Tests (with colors for Chrome/Firefox JavaScript Console)
test('Skip key not defined', {}, { a: 1 }, {});
test('Empty definition', { a: {} }, { a: 1 }, {});
test('Use default when key is missing', { a: { default: 10 } }, {}, { a: 10 });
test('Keep key with valid definitions', { a: { default: 10 }, b: { ko: 'def' } }, {}, { a: 10 });

test('Use default when value is not valid ', { a: { default: 10, validation: () => false } }, { a: 1 }, { a: 10 });
test('Use value when it is valid          ', { a: { default: 10, validation: () => true  } }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1 });
test('Use converted value when it is valid', { a: { convert: (a: number, k: string) => `${k}=${a * 2}`, validation: () => true } }, { a: 1 }, { a: 'a=2' });

function test<D>(message: string, definitions: D, query: Query, expected: SelectorResult<D>) {
  const actual = selector(definitions, query);
  const args = [expected, actual].map(x => JSON.stringify(x));
  if (args[0] === args[1]) {
    console.log(`%c ✔️ ${message}`, 'color: Green; background: #EFE;');
  } else {
    console.log(`%c ❌ ${message} KO : Expected ${args[0]}, Received ${args[1]}`, 'color: Red; background: #FEE;');
  }
}
```

The code can be evaluated and executed in the TypeScript Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F55940132%2Fconvert-the-function-to-use-typescript-types%2F55969899%2355969899%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Better%20results%20with%20compiler%20option%20--strictNullChecks%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Types%0D%0Atype%20QueryValue%20%3D%20any%3B%0D%0Atype%20Query%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20QueryValue%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Definition%3CT1%2C%20T2%3DT1%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20validation%3F%3A%20(value%3A%20QueryValue)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20convert%20%20%20%3F%3A%20(value%3A%20QueryValue%2C%20key%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20T1%3B%0D%0A%20%20default%20%20%20%3F%3A%20T2%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20WithValidation%20%3D%20%7B%20validation%3A%20(value%3A%20QueryValue)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20WithConvert%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20convert%20%20%20%3A%20(value%3A%20QueryValue%2C%20key%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20WithDefault%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20default%20%20%20%3A%20T%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SelectorResult%3CD%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BP%20in%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20D%5D%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20D%5BK%5D%20extends%20WithDefault%3Cany%3E%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%20%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20D%5D%5D%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20D%5BP%5D%20extends%20WithDefault%3Cinfer%20T%3E%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BP%20in%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20D%5D%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20D%5BK%5D%20extends%20WithDefault%3Cany%3E%20%3F%20never%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20D%5BK%5D%20extends%20WithConvert%3Cany%3E%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20D%5BK%5D%20extends%20WithValidation%20%20%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20D%5BK%5D%20extends%20Definition%3Cany%3E%20%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%20%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20D%5D%5D%3F%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20D%5BP%5D%20extends%20WithValidation%20%26%20WithConvert%3Cinfer%20T%3E%20%3F%20T%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20D%5BP%5D%20extends%20Definition%3Cany%3E%20%3F%20unknown%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20--%20Test%20Types%20--%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test1%20%3D%20SelectorResult%3C%7B%20a%3A%20'invalid'%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Not%20a%20%60Definition%3CT%3E%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20Expected%20%60%7B%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3E%3E%20Received%20%60%7B%7D%20%26%20%7B%7D%60%20%3A%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test2%20%3D%20SelectorResult%3C%7B%20a%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20~%60Definition%3Cunknown%3E%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20Expected%20%60%7B%20a%3F%3A%20unknown%20%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3E%3E%20Received%20%60%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20a%3F%3A%20unknown%20%7D%60%20%3A%20~OK%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test3%20%3D%20SelectorResult%3C%7B%20a%3A%20WithConvert%3Cany%3E%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60convert%60%20alone%20is%20ignored.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20Expected%20%60%7B%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3E%3E%20Received%20%60%7B%7D%20%26%20%7B%7D%60%20%3A%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test4%20%3D%20SelectorResult%3C%7B%20a%3A%20WithDefault%3Cnumber%3E%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60default%60%20ensures%20the%20key%20is%20kept%20and%20provides%20the%20value%20type%3A%20%60number%60.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20Expected%20%60%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3E%3E%20Received%20%60%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%7D%60%20%3A%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test5%20%3D%20SelectorResult%3C%7B%20a%3A%20WithDefault%3Cnumber%3E%20%26%20WithConvert%3Cany%3E%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Idem%20Test%204%3A%20%60convert()%60%20still%20ignored%2C%20only%20%60default%60%20matters.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20Expected%20%60%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3E%3E%20Received%20%60%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%7D%60%20%3A%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test6%20%3D%20SelectorResult%3C%7B%20a%3A%20WithValidation%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60validation()%60%20alone%20makes%20the%20key%20optional%20and%20the%20value%20type%20%60unknown%60.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20Expected%20%60%7B%20a%3F%3A%20unknown%20%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3E%3E%20Received%20%60%7B%7D%20%26%20%7B%20a%3F%3A%20unknown%20%7D%60%20%3A%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test7%20%3D%20SelectorResult%3C%7B%20a%3A%20WithValidation%20%26%20WithConvert%3Cstring%3E%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Idem%20Test6%20%2B%20%60convert()%60%20providing%20the%20value%20type%3A%20%60string%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20Expected%20%60%7B%20a%3F%3A%20string%20%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3E%3E%20Received%20%60%7B%7D%20%26%20%7B%20a%3F%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%7D%60%20%3A%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test8%20%3D%20SelectorResult%3C%7B%20a%3A%20WithDefault%3Cnumber%3E%3B%20b%3A%20'invalid'%3B%20c%3A%20WithValidation%20%7D%3E%3B%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Combining%20several%20keys%20from%20different%20cases%3A%20a%20(Test4)%2C%20b%20(Test1)%2C%20c%20(Test6)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20Expected%20%60%7B%20a%3A%20number%3B%20c%3F%3A%20unknown%20%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3E%3E%20Received%20%60%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20c%3F%3A%20unknown%20%7D%60%20%3A%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Implementation%0D%0Aconst%20keySelector%20%3D%20%3CD%2C%20Q%3E(definitions%3A%20D%2C%20query%3A%20Q%2C%20key%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20val%20%3D%20query%5Bkey%20as%20keyof%20Q%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20def%20%3D%20definitions%5Bkey%20as%20keyof%20D%5D%20as%20Definition%3CD%5Bkeyof%20D%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20val%20!%3D%3D%20'undefined'%20%26%26%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20typeof%20def.validation%20!%3D%3D%20'undefined'%20%26%26%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20def.validation(val))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20def.convert%20!%3D%3D%20'undefined'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20%7B%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20def.convert(val%2C%20key)%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20val%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20typeof%20def.default%20!%3D%3D%20'undefined'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20%7B%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20def.default%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20safeSelector%20%3D%20%3CD%3E(definitions%3A%20D%2C%20query%3A%20Query)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20Object.keys(definitions).reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(result%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20Object.assign(result%2C%20keySelector(definitions%2C%20query%2C%20key))%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%7D%20as%20SelectorResult%3CD%3E)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20selector%20%3D%20%3CD%3E(definitions%3A%20D%2C%20query%3A%20Query%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%3D%3E%20safeSelector(definitions%2C%20query%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Tests%20(with%20colors%20for%20Chrome%2FFirefox%20JavaScript%20Console)%0D%0Atest('Skip%20key%20not%20defined'%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0Atest('Empty%20definition'%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0Atest('Use%20default%20when%20key%20is%20missing'%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20default%3A%2010%20%7D%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%2010%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Atest('Keep%20key%20with%20valid%20definitions'%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20default%3A%2010%20%7D%2C%20b%3A%20%7B%20ko%3A%20'def'%20%7D%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%2010%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atest('Use%20default%20when%20value%20is%20not%20valid%20'%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20default%3A%2010%2C%20validation%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20false%20%7D%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%2010%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Atest('Use%20value%20when%20it%20is%20valid%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20default%3A%2010%2C%20validation%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20true%20%20%7D%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Atest('Use%20converted%20value%20when%20it%20is%20valid'%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20convert%3A%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20k%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%60%24%7Bk%7D%3D%24%7Ba%20*%202%7D%60%2C%20validation%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20true%20%7D%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%20'a%3D2'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test%3CD%3E(message%3A%20string%2C%20definitions%3A%20D%2C%20query%3A%20Query%2C%20expected%3A%20SelectorResult%3CD%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20actual%20%3D%20selector(definitions%2C%20query)%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20args%20%3D%20%5Bexpected%2C%20actual%5D.map(x%20%3D%3E%20JSON.stringify(x))%3B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(args%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20args%5B1%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60%25c%20%E2%9C%94%EF%B8%8F%20%24%7Bmessage%7D%60%2C%20'color%3A%20Green%3B%20background%3A%20%23EFE%3B')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60%25c%20%E2%9D%8C%20%24%7Bmessage%7D%20KO%20%3A%20Expected%20%24%7Bargs%5B0%5D%7D%2C%20Received%20%24%7Bargs%5B1%5D%7D%60%2C%20'color%3A%20Red%3B%20background%3A%20%23FEE%3B')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) with every "strict" compiler options like `--strictNullChecks`.