# Testing mapped type

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, types

Answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55969899/8634147), I had to test the complex mapped type `SelectorResult`. I've used two kinds of tests:

- Unit tests: automatisable but based on values so limited to test types
- Manual checking of type aliases: is `SelectorResult<{ a: 'invalid' }>` proceeded by the TypeScript compiler and with the expected output (here `{}`)?

Is there a way to write automated type tests in TypeScript, for instance where the TypeScript compiler warns us about an unexpected type?

Answer (score 0):

*This is my own attempt to resolve this problem.*

I came to a solution that is not very elegant but that can leverage the TypeScript compiler to check a computed type. The tip is to call a function `checkExtends<A, B extends A>()` twice: `checkExtends<Expected, Actual>(); checkExtends<Actual, Expected>();` to check that both types `Actual` and `Expected` are strictly structurally compatible.

I've made a computed type `PropDiff<A, B>` (see at the end) to help spot type differences, listing:

- the keys in A that are not B: `{ [k]: { left: A[k] } }`
- the keys in B that are not A: `{ [k]: { right: B[k] } }`
- the property with the same key but a different value type: `{ [k]: { left: A[k], right: B[k] } }`

The final pattern is composed of 5 lines:

```
type TestN_Actual   = TBD;
type TestN_Expected = TBD; 
type TestN_Differ   = PropDiff<TestN_Actual, TestN_Expected>;
checkExtends<TestN_Expected, TestN_Actual>();
checkExtends<TestN_Actual, TestN_Expected>();
```

Example:

```
type Test2_Actual   = { a: 1 } & {};
type Test2_Expected = { a: number }; 
type Test2_Differ   = PropDiff<Test2_Actual, Test2_Expected>;
checkExtends<Test2_Expected, Test2_Actual>();
checkExtends<Test2_Actual, Test2_Expected>(); // Error for 'Test2_Expected': "Types of property 'a' are incompatible..."
```

Helpers code:

```
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;

type KeyDiff<A, B> = Diff<keyof A, keyof B>;
type ValDiffKey<A, B> = { [K in keyof A]: K extends keyof B ? A[K] extends B[K] ? B[K] extends A[K] ? never : K : K : never }[keyof A];

type PropDiff<A, B> = {
    [P in KeyDiff<A, B> | KeyDiff<B, A> | ValDiffKey<A, B>]:
        P extends keyof A ?
            P extends keyof B ?
                { left: A[P], right: B[P] } :
                { left: A[P] } :
        P extends keyof B ?
            { right: B[P] } :
            never;
};

function checkExtends<A, B extends A>() {}
```

Example used to validate `PropDiff<A, B>`:

```
type Test1_Actual = PropDiff<
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 1, d: 1 },
    { a: number, b: {}, c: 1, e: 1 }>;
type Test1_Expected = {
    a: { left: 1, right: number },
    b: { left: 2, right: {} },
    d: { left: 1 },
    e: { right: 1 }
}; 
checkExtends<Test1_Expected, Test1_Actual>();
checkExtends<Test1_Actual, Test1_Expected>();
```

[Whole code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Diff%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20U%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20KeyDiff%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%3D%20Diff%3Ckeyof%20A%2C%20keyof%20B%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20ValDiffKey%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20A%5D%3A%20K%20extends%20keyof%20B%20%3F%20A%5BK%5D%20extends%20B%5BK%5D%20%3F%20B%5BK%5D%20extends%20A%5BK%5D%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20K%20%3A%20K%20%3A%20never%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20PropDiff%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20KeyDiff%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%7C%20KeyDiff%3CB%2C%20A%3E%20%7C%20ValDiffKey%3CA%2C%20B%3E%5D%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P%20extends%20keyof%20A%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P%20extends%20keyof%20B%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20left%3A%20A%5BP%5D%2C%20right%3A%20B%5BP%5D%20%7D%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20left%3A%20A%5BP%5D%20%7D%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P%20extends%20keyof%20B%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20right%3A%20B%5BP%5D%20%7D%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20never%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20checkExtends%3CA%2C%20B%20extends%20A%3E()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test1_Actual%20%3D%20PropDiff%3C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%201%2C%20d%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20c%3A%201%2C%20e%3A%201%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20Test1_Expected%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%7B%20left%3A%201%2C%20right%3A%20number%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%7B%20left%3A%202%2C%20right%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20d%3A%20%7B%20left%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20e%3A%20%7B%20right%3A%201%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%20%0D%0AcheckExtends%3CTest1_Expected%2C%20Test1_Actual%3E()%3B%0D%0AcheckExtends%3CTest1_Actual%2C%20Test1_Expected%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test2_Actual%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Test2_Expected%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%20%0D%0Atype%20Test2_Differ%20%3D%20PropDiff%3CTest2_Actual%2C%20Test2_Expected%3E%3B%0D%0AcheckExtends%3CTest2_Expected%2C%20Test2_Actual%3E()%3B%0D%0AcheckExtends%3CTest2_Actual%2C%20Test2_Expected%3E()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%20for%20'Test2_Expected'%3A%20%22Types%20of%20property%20'a'%20are%20incompatible...%22%0D%0A).